# when click back button, the app crashs after a seceond

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, back-button

I have customized back button. when I click on it, the application crashes after a second.
here is the code:
[error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQata.png)

```
    private var mBackPressed: Long = 0
    private val timeInterval = 2000



    private fun configBackPress() {
        requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this, true) {
            when {
                mBackPressed + timeInterval > System.currentTimeMillis() -> {
                   
                    requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()
                }
                else -> {
                    Snackbar.make(
                        requireActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content),
                        getString(R.string.press_once_again_back_button_to_exit),
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT
                    )
                        .setAnchorView(viewBinding.vSnackBarHelper)
                        .show()

                    mBackPressed = System.currentTimeMillis()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

when the user click two times on back button, the back should work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: Would you mind adding the log with the exception?

Comment: Where do you call the `configBackPress` method? It could be a NPE exception on this line `requireActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content)`. Can you share your XML layout?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

before calling `requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()`. you should set `isEnabled` to **false** because if we go through the onBackPressed source code we see:
[image]

it looks for active callbacks and if found any calls them and returns. that's what makes the loop.

your code should be:

```
isEnabled = false
requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()
```

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()
```

with just

```
finish()
```

currently your `onBackPressedDispatcher` set in `Fragment` is calling `onBackPressed` in (`require`d) `Activity`, which will at first try to propagate this event to own childrens - `Fragment`s. so, again, `onBackPressedDispatcher` will be triggered, again it will call `Activity`s method and this is an endless loop depicted in your log screenshot (btw. never post code/log/text as image!)

edit: `isEnabled = false` is a better approach, just wanted to leave you some case description